# extract manytomany field from a queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

**Models.py**

```
class AllotmentDocket(models.Model):

    sales_order = models.ForeignKey(MaterialRequest, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='allotment_sales')

class MaterialRequest(models.Model):

    kit = models.ForeignKey(Kit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='kit')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Kit(models.Model):
    kit_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=0)
    components_per_kit = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name='kit_product')
```

How can I get all the products information through the related AllotmentDocket?

I tried :

```
def PrintAllotmentDocket(request, pk):
    AlotmentDocket = get_object_or_404(AllotmentDocket, id=pk)

    kit = MaterialRequest.objects.filter(id=AlotmentDocket.sales_order).values('kit')
```

but this gives an error:

> int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not
>   'MaterialRequest'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with

```
Product.objects.filter(
    kit_product__kit__allotment_sales=pk
)
```

with `pk` the primary key of the `AllotmentDocket` (so the one passed to the view).

> **Note**: the `related_name` is the name of the relation in *reverse*, not the relation in the direction in which you define it.